# Salesforce DX - How to avoid "Field is not writeable" error when versioning a package

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package

I'm trying to version a package that has a class that creates a Task record setting it's createdById. The assignment looks like this:

```
newTask.CreatedById = Utils.userID;
```

However, when trying to version the DX package by running the following command:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p sf-common-classes --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json -d force-app -k Password123 --wait 10 --codecoverage 
--targetdevhubusername DevHub
```

We get an error: Field is not writeable: Task.CreatedById

Please note that this file is already saved in our Production Org (DevHub) and the feature already works.

Here is how our scratch org definition file looks like:

```
{
  "orgName": "Anything for this post",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "StateAndCountryPicklist",
    "PersonAccounts",
    "ProductsAndSchedules",
    "LiveAgent",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "Communities",
    "EinsteinBuilderFree",
    "AddCustomRelationships:5",
    "FieldAuditTrail"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your original orgs including the scratch org or developer org can manually enable the feature **Enable Create Audit Fields** by following instructions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334139&type=1&mode=1)

When you create an unlocked/2GP package version, a scratch org is created behind scenes and you do not have any control over the same.

Unfortunately, there is no setting in Metadata API to expose  **Enable Create Audit Fields** at this point. So you cannot add them to setting object in your scratch org definition file.

**Workaround**

Modify your test class and move away from directly assigning the **CreatedById** field.

Instead simply use `System.RunAs() {}` with appropriate user to create the Task so the createdBy is set to the user you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing compilation issue you can use SObject and try to add the field as shown below.

```
SObjectType taskSObjectType = Get your Task SObject Type;        
SObject taskSObject = taskSObjectType.newSObject();
taskSObject.put('CreatedById', Utils.userID);
```

Not sure if this will fail test class run or not. But should not give any compilation issue.

Comment: The test run will fail here and test run is also done during package creation! Hence the package creation will be blocked!

Comment: Ok, in that case, this wont help.